# makefile for c++11 doesn't work

Tags: c++, c++11, makefile

I am new to makefiles. I created the following makefile:

```
CC=g++
DEBUG= -g
CFLAGS=-c -Wall -std=c++11 $(DEBUG)

all: hello

hello: ConsoleApplication1.o clock.o communication.o device_manager.o devices.o 
    $(CC) ConsoleApplication1.o clock.o communication.o device_manager.o devices.o 

ConsoleApplication1.o: ConsoleApplication1.cpp
        $(CC) $(CFGLAS) ConsoleApplication1.cpp

clock.o: clock.cpp clock.h
        $(CC) $(CFGLAS) clock.cpp

communication.o: communication.cpp 
        $(CC) $(CFGLAS) communication.cpp

device_manager.o: device_manager.cpp 
        $(CC) $(CFGLAS) device_manager.cpp

devices.o: devices.cpp 
        $(CC) $(CFGLAS) devices.cpp

clean:
    rm -rf *.o hello
```

I put the makefile in the directory of all the code files and run the command "make" from the command line.

I got many errors like:

> ConsoleApplication1.cpp:494:30: error: ‘chrono’ is not a member of ‘std’
>        mytime::duration_timer_t    timer;
>                                 ^
>   ConsoleApplication1.cpp:494:30: error: ‘chrono’ is not a member of ‘std’
>   ConsoleApplication1.cpp:494:55: error: template argument 1 is invalid
>        mytime::duration_timer_t    timer;
>                                                          ^
>   ConsoleApplication1.cpp:494:65: error: invalid type in declaration before ‘;’ token
>        mytime::duration_timer_t    timer;
>                                                                    ^
>   ConsoleApplication1.cpp:495:11: error: request for member ‘set_duration’ in ‘timer’, which is of non-class type ‘int’
>        timer.set_duration(std::chrono::seconds(120));
>              ^
>   ConsoleApplication1.cpp:495:29: error: ‘std::chrono’ has not been declared
>        timer.set_duration(std::chrono::seconds(120));
>                                ^
>   ConsoleApplication1.cpp:496:16: error: request for member ‘start’ in ‘timer’, which is of non-class type ‘int’
>        for( timer.start(); not(timer.expired()); )

When I compile excactly the same file codes in codeBlocks it compiles, so I guess that I have some mistake in the make file.
I have one header file in my project name "general.h" which doesn't have a cpp file. Should I put it also in the makefile?

Comment: In your `hello` label, you are trying to compile `.o` files.

Comment: `-std=c+11` should be replaced with `-std=c++11`

Comment: `-std=c+11` should be `-std=c++11`.

Comment: @Aleph0 I do the same thing in my makefiles... They generate the `.o` files fine.

Comment: @Aleph0- it's supposed to be like that. (e.g https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aw9wHbFTnAQ)

Comment: @Hyperum The line in question does not generate the .o files, it links them to an executable ;-).

Comment: Are you not include ```<chrono>```?

Comment: Generally spoken, I would think that after setting CC and CFLAGS the actual rules for making the various binaries are known to make. (The built-in defaults should be fine.) Only the dependencies need to be specified.

Comment: @ Jorn Vernee- I inluded it in my code. As I wrote the code soed compile successfuly in the codeBlock.

Comment: I don't think `clock.h` should be in your `clock.o` label

Comment: Make sure you use the same compiler in both environments (try "which g++" or equivalent on the console and check the settings in your GUI)  and that the makefile compilation actually finds the headers (if not, that should be one of the first errors and is easily overlooked).

Comment: I think you also should add the directive `-o hello` somewhere to create the executable

Comment: @Aleph0 Good point (it should be in the rule for hello, the line with the .o files), but not the source of the problems.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Your rules say `$(CFGLAS)`, not `$(CFLAGS)`.**

That means `-std=c++11` is never passed to the compiler, so C++11 features don't exist for you.

Pay more attention to detail!

You will also need to pass `$(CFLAGS)` to `$(CC)` in your `hello` rule, otherwise your compiler invocations will be out of sync and all hell may break loose.

Comment: @BarryTheHatchet- thanks! Now it compiles. Can you explain about the last part in your answer. How I pass $(CFLAGS) to $(CC) ?

Comment: @sara8: The same way you did in all of your other targets.

Comment: @ BarryTheHatchet- what about the file which don't have cpp file (general.h). Should I include it?

Comment: @sara8: Do you think you should include it? If so, why? If not, why not?

Comment: @ BarryTheHatchet- I would think it should because the compiler should check all the files, but as I can see the o files are made only for the cpp files....so I am confused.

Comment: @sara8: Your header is already being "checked" by the compiler, because it's become part of your source file via the `#include` statement.

Answer (score 0):

While you *compile* your object files with `-std=c++11` you link them without that flag. Have you tried adding `-std=c++11` to `hello` rule?

Comment: The linker doesn't need to know about C++ (apart from the libraries to link)

Comment: "apart from the libraries to link" is a big deal